# How to use new Blender 3.2 volumetric motion blur

Tags: shader-nodes, motion-blur

So I did a simple volumetric animation (animated using map node) , but when I render the image I can't see any motion blur. I used cycles and enabled motion blur in the render settings and made the animation play very fast but even then I can't see any blur the volumetric noise details details are still very sharp.

Comment: Is the motion blur visible on other objects?

Comment: Yes, they are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure motion blur is visible on an object, it has to have motion blur enabled in the *Object Properties* Tab:

[image]

Please note that the new motion blur is updated for simulations, not volumetric materials. If you are using a smoke/fluid simulation, then the motion blur will be visible. A material animation is still a still object, even though the value is animated, so Blender won't take it as a moving object.

The new motion blur is updated for fluid/smoke simulations, not materials or a volumetrics animation on a still object!

Comment: Yes, the motion blur is enabled and it's a material with volumetric shader. Then is there any way I can see motion blur on material?

Comment: I don't think so...maybe add it in post? There's a Vector Blur node in the Compositor which might help.

Comment: @SamuelSullins Yes, there is vector blur but the question mentioned motion blur.

Comment: @Blenderstarter I will edit my answer to include any way to add motion blur to materials, probably by Vector blur as Samuel said.

Comment: I will try to use the compositor . Thank you for your answer.